# Add item to multi-level array (Telegram Bot)

Tags: php, arrays, telegram-bot

I have the following array:

```
$keyboard = ['inline_keyboard' => [[['text' => 'text1', 'callback_data' => 'something1']],[['text' => 'text2', 'callback_data' => 'something2']],]];
```

How do I add one element (with `text` and `callback_data`) to the end of the array (in a foreach-loop)?

So my goal is to have after a while the following array:

```
$keyboard = ['inline_keyboard' => [[['text' => 'text1', 'callback_data' => 'something1']],[['text' => 'text2', 'callback_data' => 'something2']],[['text' => 'text3', 'callback_data' => 'something3']],[['text' => 'text4', 'callback_data' => 'something4']],]];
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array_push to the rescue!

```
<?php
$keyboard = ['inline_keyboard' => [
    [
        ['text' => 'text1', 'callback_data' => 'something1']
    ],
    [
        ['text' => 'text2', 'callback_data' => 'something2']
    ],
]];

array_push($keyboard['inline_keyboard'], ['text' => 'text3', 'callback_data' => 'something3']);

var_dump($keyboard);
```

**Yields:**

```
array(1) {
  ["inline_keyboard"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["text"]=>
        string(5) "text1"
        ["callback_data"]=>
        string(10) "something1"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["text"]=>
        string(5) "text2"
        ["callback_data"]=>
        string(10) "something2"
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["text"]=>
      string(5) "text3"
      ["callback_data"]=>
      string(10) "something3"
    }
  }
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c92ad23fccc0c6d102761840f051cdb4b6c4084b